# Expected: 0, instead got: 1 Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a task to create a function that returns the total number of smiley faces. Valid smiley faces look like: ":) :D ;-D :~)" and invalid smiling faces: ";( :> :} :] ".

My solution below throws the following error message "expected 0 instead got 1".

```
def count_smileys(arr)
  arr.count do |element|
   [":)", ":D", ";-D", ":~)", ";~D", "8~(", ";(", ":>", ":}", ":]",
 "8~P", "8-(", "; )", ";-P", ":~P", "~P", ":~P", "~P", "; (", ":-)",
 "8~D", "~)", "8D", "~)", "8 )", "; )", "~)", ":-D", " (", ";D",
 "8-D", "8-P", ";-D", ": D", ";~D", " ("].include?(element)
  end
end
```

As it stands my solution passes 4 out of 5 basic tests:

```
 Basic tests
Test Passed: Value == 0
Test Passed: Value == 4
Test Passed: Value == 2
Test Passed: Value == 1
Expected: 0, instead got: 1
```

I've tried removing the parameters but that only worked for the last test and failed me on the rest. Any suggestions? Thanks

Example tests below:

```
Test.describe("Basic tests") do
Test.assert_equals(count_smileys([]), 0)
Test.assert_equals(count_smileys([":D",":~)",";~D",":)"]), 4)
Test.assert_equals(count_smileys([":)",":(",":D",":O",":;"]), 2)
Test.assert_equals(count_smileys([";]", ":[", ";*", ":$", ";-D"]), 1)
Test.assert_equals(count_smileys([";", ")", ";*", ":$", "8-D"]), 0)
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example input and the expect output?

Comment: Just added to question.

Comment: `"8-D"` is in your base array but seems as if it should not be for the tests.

Comment: Using Array#count to count truthy matches is hard to debug. Using `Array#&(other_array).size` (or #count, if you prefer) is less obscure and easier to inspect IMHO.

Comment: Why is the last test supposed to return `0` given that the test array's last element `"8-D"` _is_ contained in your array of smileys? (1st element in the last row)

Answer (score 0):

### Compare or Inspect Using Array Intersection

You don't show your actual test setup, so I won't address that. However, it seems like you're trying to count the number of smileys in a given array using the block form of [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-count). It's arguably simpler to measure the size of an Array intersection, or to inspect the contents of the intersection, using [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-26). For example:

```
SMILEYS = [
  ":)", ":D", ";-D", ":~)", ";~D", "8~(", ";(", ":>", ":}", ":]",
 "8~P", "8-(", "; )", ";-P", ":~P", "~P", ":~P", "~P", "; (", ":-)",
 "8~D", "~)", "8D", "~)", "8 )", "; )", "~)", ":-D", " (", ";D",
 "8-D", "8-P", ";-D", ": D", ";~D", " ("
]

SMILEYS.&([":D", ":~)", ";~D", ":)"]).size == 4
#=> true

SMILEYS.&([":)", ":(", ":D", ":O", ":;"]).size == 2
#=> true

SMILEYS.&([";]", ":[", ";*", ":$", ";-D"]).size == 1
#=> true

SMILEYS.&([";", ")", ";*", ":$", "8-D"]).size == 0
#=> false
```

Note that the last comparison is false because `8-D` is defined in your list of *SMILEYS*. Specifically:

```
SMILEYS.&([";", ")", ";*", ":$", "8-D"])
#=> ["8-D"]
```

so the expected value should be `1` unless `8-D` doesn't really belong in your array of acceptable values. If that's the case, remove it from the variable or constant containing your allowable values.

Comment: Intersection gives the unique elements. If a smiley appears more then once, then `.count` and the `.&.size` give different results.